# Existe alguma diferença funcional entre as funções bind_rows (dplyr) e a função rbind.fill (plyr) no R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

Gostaria de saber se utilizar uma função ao invés de outra haveria algum diferencial em relação ao dataframe final a ser produzido. Houve situações em que tentei realizar `bind_rows` entre dataframes (ou tibbles) diferentes e tive erro (ex.: 'Error: tinyformat: Too many conversion specifiers in format string') e, que se fosse utilizada a função `rbind.fill` no lugar, o mesmo erro não ocorria e a junção dos dataframes funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Forneça um exemplo de quando esse erro aconteceu.